# How to cleanly stop an "ng test" command in a terminal window

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I am trying to find the best way to stop an "ng test" command when running Jasmine unit tests for my Angular project. I have looked through a lot of Angular's documentation, but there doesn't seem to be a clean why to cancel "ng test" once it starts. Entering Ctrl-C or Ctrl-Z both don't do anything and I am trying not to force quit the terminal window or the process to stop it. Any recommendations or ideas of how to do this would be greatly appreciated.